# zabbix busqueda en logs de varios servicios

Tags: zabbix

buen día
estoy implementado zabbix junto con grafana para leer logs de errores y esto mostrarlos en una grafica, sin embargo tengo varios clientes que utilizan diferentes rutas, sin embargo es el mismo log

es maso menos asi, en donde el asterisco (*) depende del cliente: yoyo,esika,papiro, etc y que en el archivo consulta.log todo lo que sea ERROR CHANCE

log.count[/libre/switch/*/sw_chance/logs/consulta.log,"ERRO_CHANCE","UTF-8"]

sin embargo esto no es exitoso

¿como puedo hacer par que me tome todos los clientes y luego en grafana pueda mostrar cada uno de los clientes.